# How to create a custom event view in powershell?

Tags: powershell, event-viewer, powershell-5.0

I've been looking around and can't find any way to create a custom view in the event viewer in Powershell.

[image]

I found a Microsoft Scripting Guy post about exporting one, but I'd like to create one from scratch. I'm using PowerShell 5.0.

**Edit:**
Looks like all the event logs are stored in `%SystemRoot%\System32\Winevt\Logs\` and exist as `.evtx` files.

**Edit:**
The command:

```
 New-EventLog -LogName "LogNameHere" -Source "Test"
```

does create `LogNameHere.evtx` in the `%SystemRoot%\System32\Winevt\Logs\` directory. You can specify multiple sources, but this just allows those sources to write to the event log, and doesn't log all the information from those sources. (I'll check on that)

```
 New-EventLog -LogName "LogNameHere" -Source "Test1", "Test2", "Test3"
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/29695358/programmatically-create-a-custom-eventlog-view shows how to do it in C#, but it appears to just be XML manipulation anyway.

Comment: @Eris Thanks for the link. Don't think I saw that one. Most of the articles I read had to do with exporting XML from an already existing custom event.